# Can’t connect Express.js server to the Angular frontend

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, mongodb, express

I created a Node.js application and also an Angular application.  I need to get data from the database and also store data to the database. I'm having problems connecting my Express.js server to the Angular application.

#### File *user.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../User';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BASE_URL } from '../const/config';
import { MONGO_EXPRESS_URL } from '../const/config';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${MONGO_EXPRESS_URL}/fetchdata`);
  }
}
```

#### File *users.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import { User } from '../../User';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css'],
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[] = [];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => (this.users = users));
  }
}
```

This error pops up when I run the Angular application:

[image]

#### File *server.js*

```
app.use("/", router);

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Server is running on Port: " + port);
});

router.route("/fetchdata").get(function (req, res) {
  users.find({}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should kind of look like this on your Node.js. You should set up the Express.js server like so:

```
constructor() {
  this.app = express()
}

Initialize{
    this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT');
      if('OPTIONS' === req.method){
        res.sendStatus(200);
      }
      else {
          next();
      }
    })

  this.app.use(RouterWebservices)

    this.app.listen(your.HttpPort, your.Ip, () => {
      console.log('Server now listening at ', your.HttpPort, 'IP ', your.Ip);
    })
}
```

Then you need to declare your variables in a *router.webservice.ts* file:

```
export const RouterWebservices = express.Router()

RouterWebservices.get('/fetchdata', FetchWebservice)
```

And write a FetchWebserivce where you simply answer the request with data.

Comment: hey man i added the /fetchdata route to the question if anything need to change please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the route: *https://localhost:4000*.

It would be *http://localhost:4000* (http:// instead of http**s**://).

Comment: What is *the reason* for it? Why doesn't it work with [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)? Is there a story behind it? Preferably, please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://XXXX), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).